# How to apply the filter over the result set returned in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My SQL query returns this result set here:

```
Person_id   Product_id  Discount_id  Discount_Rule  Active_Thru
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1001        322         251         R1            '2016-12-23 21:36:38.890'
  1001        323         251         R1            '2017-01-23 21:36:38.890'
  1001        324         252         R2            '2016-12-23 21:50:30.933'
```

I need to get the result set as below by applying a filter on the above result set. That is to get discount ids used for a person from the above result set only.

```
Person_id   Discount_id  Discount_Rule    Active_Thru
------------------------------------------------------------------
1001         251           R1            '2016-12-23 21:50:30.933'
1001         252           R2            '2016-12-23 21:50:30.933'
```

Sample SQLFiddle is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f20/1/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `DISTINCT` clause, like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Person_ID
    , Discount_ID
FROM Table
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2198c/2) with how the above code works.

An alternative is to use `GROUP BY`, but they both evaluate to the same execution plan in this scenario, so pick whichever you like:

```
SELECT
    Person_ID
    , Discount_ID
FROM table
GROUP BY Person_ID
    , Discount_ID
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2198c/3) with how the above code works.

**Update:**

As you mentioned in the comments, you need to build on this and return the minimum `active_thru` date for a combination of Person_ID, Discount_ID and Discount_Rule.

For this you need a query like below:

```
SELECT
    Person_ID
    , Discount_ID
    , Discount_Rule
    , MIN(Active_thru) 'Min_Active_Thru'
FROM test
group by Person_id
  , Discount_Id
  , Discount_Rule
```

You can also see how this query works in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f20/4).

Comment: Forgot to add two more columns otherwise I could not reproduce my exact scenario. Here is the modified SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97f20/1/0. From the result sets of this fiddle I am trying to get minimum active_thru date for a combination of person_id,discount_id and discount_rule

Comment: @user3742125 Well, that changes the question a bit. Please update the question with this information, so as my answer and your question will be in line.

Comment: Updated, could you help me on this

Comment: okay...Is there any other way to do it. I mean by using OVER clause. Because I have some calculations in my select statements so I cannot simply use GROUP BY as u mentioned.

Comment: @user3742125 Well, we can stop beating around the bush and if you can provide a SQLFiddle link with some sample data and your final query .. and more details as to how you want the final result, maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using group by as below:

```
SELECT person_id, discount_id
FROM table
GROUP BY person_id, discount_id
```